# How to view the SQL query being run while using go gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am working on crud api using go-gorm. I want to log the exact query which is being executed on the database when I run the code(like in hibernate).

For example when `db.Create(&user)` is executed .
It should log

```sql
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`,`age`,`created_at`) VALUES ("jinzhu", 18, "2020-07-04 11:05:21.775")
```

What configuration should I do to achieve this ?

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/session.html#Debug or https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html

Comment: `db.Create(&user).Debug()`